# For what value of $x$, does the graph of $y=5x-\mathrm{e}^x$ have a horizontal tangent line?

Tags: derivatives, tangent-line

I believe I came up with an answer, however, I'm not too sure if it is valid.

Considering that the derivative of the function is $5-\mathrm{e}^x$, and the function must be equal to zero in order for the tangent line to be horizontal; $\mathrm{e}^x = 5$, so $x$ at $\ln 5$ is a horizontal tangent line.

Would I be correct in my assumptions? Or have I got this all wrong?

Comment: You are right. When $y'=0$ you have a horizontal tangent.

Answer (score 2):

The slope of the graph of $y=f(x)$ is given by $f'(x)$. So the slope of the graph of $y=5x-e^x$ is 
$$f'(x)=5-e^x$$
Where the slope is zero, $f'(x)=0$. So
$$5-e^x=0$$
$$e^x=5$$
$$x=\ln 5\approx1.6094$$
So at $x=\ln5\approx1.6094$, the slope of $y=5x-e^x$ is zero.

Here's a graph from [Wolfram Alpha](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=plot+5x-e%5Ex+and+y%3D5*ln+5-5):
[image: Wolfram Alpha]